# Store and retrieve version information in ELF file

Tags: c, linux, elf, bfd

I'm trying to figure out a good way to store and retrieve version information in C / C++ executables and libraries on Linux. I'm using the GCC compiler for my C and C++ programs.

The storage part is pretty straightforward; declaring a variable like this stores it in the .rodata section of the output file:

```c
const char MY_VERSION[] = "some_version_information";
```

However, I'm having an incredibly difficult time with retrieving the information from an external program. With shared libraries, it is fairly easy to use `dlopen` and `dlsym` to load a library and look up a symbol, but this might not be the best way to do it, and it won't work at all for executables. Also, if possible, I would like this to work with executables and libraries built for a different architecture.

I figure that since shared libraries and executables both use the ELF format, it makes sense to use a library that knows how to read ELF files. The two I was able to find are libelf and BFD; I'm struggling to find decent documentation for each. Is there perhaps a better library to use?

This is what I have so far, using BFD:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                               [6/1356]
#include <string.h>
#include <bfd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const char *filename;
    int i;
    size_t storage;
    bfd *b = NULL;
    asymbol **symbol_table;
    long num_symbols;

    if(argc != 2) return 1; // todo: print a useful message
    else filename = argv[1];

    b = bfd_openr(filename, NULL);

    if(b == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: failed to open %s\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }

    // make sure we're opening a file that BFD understands
    if(!bfd_check_format(b, bfd_object)){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: unrecognized format\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // how much memory is needed to store the symbol table
    storage = bfd_get_symtab_upper_bound(b);

    if(storage < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: unable to find storage bound of symbol table\n");
        return 1;
    } else if((symbol_table = malloc(storage)) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: failed to allocate memory for symbol table\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        num_symbols = bfd_canonicalize_symtab(b, symbol_table);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < num_symbols; i++){
        if(strcmp(symbol_table[i]->name, "MY_VERSION") == 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "found MY_VERSION\n");

            // todo: print the string?
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I realize that printing the string may not be very simple due to the ELF format.

Is there a straightforward way to print a string symbol that is stored in an ELF file?

Comment: Have you tried `objdump`?

Comment: I have looked into `objdump`, `readelf`, and `nm`, but I haven't found a way to have the command print a specific symbol. Can an individual symbol be specified to `objdump`?

Comment: I doubt it, but you can always `grep` or parse the output.

Comment: Is there any reason why grepping or parsing the output of objdump would be easier than using a library to perform the equivalent lookup?

Comment: Yes. These tools already exist and are battle tested.

Comment: I see your point, but considering that objdump and friends use BFD internally, and considering that there isn't an obvious way to use these tools to accomplish precisely what I'm trying to do without potentially messy grepping / parsing, I don't think that using something like objdump is necessarily better than writing a program.

Comment: @millinon if you’re open to it, utilize pyelftools. It’s easy to accomplish very specific ELF parsing/analysis tasks using its readelf script as a reference. It’s on Github

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out that I could use a custom section to store the version information, and then just dump the section to 'extract' the string.

Here's how the version information should be declared:

```c
__attribute__((section("my_custom_version_info"))) const char MY_VERSION[] = "some.version.string";
```

Then, in the program using BFD, we can get the section a few different ways. We can use `bfd_get_section_by_name`:

```
asection *section = bfd_get_section_by_name(b, "my_custom_version_info");
```

Now that we have a handle to the section, we can load it into memory. I chose to use `bfd_malloc_and_get_section` (you should make sure `section` isn't NULL first):

```
bfd_byte *buf;
if(!bfd_malloc_and_get_section(b, section, &buf)){
    // error: failed to malloc or read the section
}
```

Now that we have the section loaded into a buffer, we can print its contents:

```
for(int i = 0; i < section->size && buf[i]; i++){
    printf("%c", buf[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Don't forget to `free` the buffer.

Comment: Better use ELF hashing to access symbols

Comment: I like this better than the `nm`-based version, as it should still work even if and after the ELF has been `strip`ped. (Theoretically, you should use a section name that does _not_ start with a dot,  as those that do are reserved)

Comment: I found that it does not work after the ELF has been stripped - the custom section does get removed. However, `strip` accepts a -K argument that specifies symbols that should not be stripped. I did not know about section names starting with a dot - I will update the answer, thanks!

Comment: BTW, there's this tool called `elfcat` that can, by name, dump the contents of an ELF section so you don't have to wire up the code in C. With it you should be able to do `elfcat --section-name my_custom_version_info a.out`  to get the string.

Comment: @millinon I couldn't reproduce that. If I strip the ELF the `strip -s` the extra section sticks.

Answer (score 2):

From inside your executable, just declare

```
 extern const char MY_VERSION[];
```

BTW, for C++ better declare `extern "C"` that symbol (even in the file defining it).

Then your issue is how to find a symbol `MY_VERSION` in some external ELF executable (the easy way could be to `popen` some `nm` process, see [nm(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html)). BTW, it is the same as for a function symbol (or for a data one). You could use a library such as [libelf](http://www.mr511.de/software/english.html) or [libelfin](https://github.com/aclements/libelfin) (or the venerable `libbfd`) or parse the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format yourself (be sure to read first [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) wikipage)

You should **learn** and understand **the ELF format**. You need to read carefully documentation on ELF and on the [x86-64 ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI). Explore existing ELF executables with [objdump(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) & [readelf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html). Read also [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html). Read how symbol tables are represented, and how their hash code is computed. Of course read in details all the possible [relocations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)). You could read Levine's book on [*Linkers and Loaders*](http://iecc.com/linkers/) and Drepper's paper on [*How to Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) (both explain ELF), and also [Assembler Language HowTo](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/), and Ian Taylor's [paper on `gold`](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/34417.pdf), and [ELF: better symbol lookup via DT_GNU_HASH](https://flapenguin.me/2017/05/10/elf-lookup-dt-gnu-hash/). See also Solaris documentation e.g. on [Hash Table Section](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-0690/chapter6-48031.html) and OSDEV [ELF tutorial](http://wiki.osdev.org/ELF_Tutorial) & [ELF](http://wiki.osdev.org/ELF) pages

You don't need any specific section (or segment).

<sup>(I've done that about 20 years ago for Sparc; it is not particularly hard)</sup>

You could also look into `emacs` source code, its [unexec.c](https://github.com/typester/emacs/blob/master/src/unexec.c) is writing some ELF file

BTW, ELF has some versioning info with symbols, see e.g. [dlvsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html)

You may also want to understand how [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)  or [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html) works, what is the virtual address space of a process (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), try `cat /proc/$$/maps`)

Comment: Agh! I was hoping that there would exist a solution that doesn't require grokking the ELF format, but I anticipated that this might be the case due to the fact that ELF is non-trivial. Still, I appreciate the specific resources - thank you!

Comment: Of course you need to understand ELF format. It is not that difficult. Otherwise just `popen` some `nm` command

Comment: I don't understand how can you want to parse ELF without understanding the ELF format (unless you use `nm`)

Comment: My goal was to find an existing tool (or library) that would accomplish the task such that I could avoid reinventing the wheel. I certainly don't dispute that parsing the ELF format requires understanding the ELF format!

Comment: `libelfin` looks elegant (but I did not use it). Did you consider using it? The examples are simple and short (e.g. [dump-syms.cc](https://github.com/aclements/libelfin/blob/master/examples/dump-syms.cc) is only 43 lines...) But you do need to understand something about ELF

Comment: I had not found libelfin - I will look into it. Thanks again!

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if it fits; but you need to spend more time in understanding ELF

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way of doing this is via SCCS what(1) strings.
See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/what.html.